# Read data from Firebase Firestore DB SWIFT UI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

As the title says, how do you read data from a firestore DB usign SwiftUI?
I have the DB created, I'm adding users and data into the DB, but, how can I read then the data from DB and, let s say, display it on the screen after? (usign SwiftUI)

Comment: The process should be fairly straightforward: 1) read from Firestore, 2) render in SwiftUI. There seem to be some good resources/tutorials out there already: https://www.google.com/search?q=swiftui+firestore What specific problem do you have here? It'll be much easier for someone to help if they know where specifically you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set the data outside of your view setup. Follow these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start.

Your data downloads into arrays and from there you can make a list view.